# Using Java to login form-based authentication .NET web application

Tags: java, sharepoint, authentication

I am trying to use Java to download a file from a form-based authentication sharepoint（as a .NET web application, but all requests are redirected to the login.aspx page. The following are the steps I use:

1. Get the file url, and it will be redirected to login page.
2. get all parameters from the page content;
3. post to login.aspx page with the parameters and account & password;
4. Then Get the file and write it into a file;

The steps 3 & 4 are redirected to the login.aspx page. Maybe the 3rd step failed?

PS,

- java tool: apache HttpClient 4.1.2
- Java Code:https://www.drivehq.com/folder/p9066489.aspx
- Log:https://www.drivehq.com/folder/p9066503.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's resolved. The steps are right, but all parameters in the post action url and post data must be encoded.

See the code:http://wind6266.blog.163.com/blog/static/67109072011926114229917/